# Where to declare variable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to declare a variable in a react-js class. The variable should be accessible in different functions. This is my code

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.testVariable= "this is a test";  // I declare the variable here
    }
    onMove() {
        console.log(this.testVariable); //I try to access it here
    }
}
```

On onMove, the value of `this.testVariable` is undefined. I Know that I could put the value on the state but I don't want to do it because each time the value changes, `render()` will be called which is not necessary. I am new to react, did I make something wrong?

Comment: You never created a variable named `test`,  you created `testVarible`.

Comment: You can call `this.onMove.bind(this);` inside the render or constructor.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using ES6 syntax in React does not bind `this` to user-defined functions however it will bind `this` to the component lifecycle methods.

So the function that you declared will not have the same context as the class and trying to access `this` will not give you what you are expecting.

For getting the context of class you have to bind the context of class to the function or use arrow functions.

Method 1 to bind the context:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);
        this.testVarible= "this is a test";
    }

    onMove() {
        console.log(this.testVarible);
    }
}
```

Method 2 to bind the context:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.testVarible= "this is a test";
    }

    onMove = () => {
        console.log(this.testVarible);
    }
}
```

**Method 2 is my preferred way** but you are free to choose your own.

**Update:** You can also create the properties on class without constructor:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {

    testVarible= "this is a test";

    onMove = () => {
        console.log(this.testVarible);
    }
}
```

**Note** If you want to update the view as well, you should use `state` and `setState` method when you set or change the value.

Example:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {

    state = { testVarible: "this is a test" };

    onMove = () => {
        console.log(this.state.testVarible);
        this.setState({ testVarible: "new value" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we set the value of this value in some other method like this.testVariable = "New Test" ?

Comment: Yes, you can set the values on this in any function. Just make sure that the function has the context as of the class. @ShubhamOjha

Comment: @BrijeshBhakta how the view will look like then ?

Comment: @user123456 not sure if I understand your question but if you are asking what will be the value of testVariable after setState method is called, it will be "new value"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `onMove` is an event handler, it is likely that its context is something other than the instance of `MyContainer`, i.e. `this` points to something different.

You can manually bind the context of the function during the construction of the instance via `Function.bind`:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);

    this.test = "this is a test";
  }

  onMove() {
    console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

---

Also, **`test !== testVariable`**.

Comment: console.log(this.testVariable) ;)

Comment: @LeonardLepadatu Thanks, almost missed that :)

Comment: or can use most elegant  `const onMove = (e) => {console.log('foo')}` and avoid to add `this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);` in constructor

Comment: I don't get the point and I get an error "Syntex error: Unexpected token" after the "const"

Comment: without `const`, sorry! The point is to simplify the handling events.

Comment: Hello @Timo what's the benefit when i declare var in `the constructor` instead of `state` Thanks in advance?