# How to pass data from parent to child in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a parent component which has 1 child. I am updating my child by passing data through props. initially, it works fine but when I click on a button and update the state using setState the child gets rendered with old values by the time setState is finished. I have solved it using componentWillReceiveProps in the child but is this the right way?

In the below code if I do setState in filterResults function it won't update the Emplist component .

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Search} from './search-bar'
import Emplist from './emplist'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.emp=[{
            name:'pawan',
            age:12
        },
        {
            name:'manish',
            age : 11
        }]
        this.state={emp:this.emp};
        this.filterResults=this.filterResults.bind(this);
    }

    filterResults(val)
    {
        if(this.state)
        {
            let filt=[];
            filt.push(
                this.emp.find(e=>{
                    return e.age==val
                })
            );
            this.setState({emp:filt});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Search filterResults={this.filterResults}/>
                <Emplist emp={this.state.emp}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

```js
EmpList Componet

import React,{Component} from 'react'

export default class Emp extends Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.emplist=this.props.emp.map(e=>{return <li>{e.name}</li>});
        this.next=this.emplist;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps,nextState,prevProps,prevState,nextContext,prevContext){
        // this.props.updated(this.props.empo);
        this.next=nextProps.emp[0];
        if(this.next)
            this.emplist= nextProps.emp.map(e=>{return <li>{e.name}</li>});
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.next)
            return <div>name not found</div>
        else
            return (
                <div>
                    <br/>
                    <p>The list is here</p>
                    <ul>
                        {this.emplist}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the correct way. if you do not need to use those values for some complex things or anything else in child, you can directly use them with `this.props.someValue` will work as same.

Comment: in child, i used nextProps since i was not able to get updated props when the child renders . how this.props.someValue will work in child ?

Comment: Can you give full code of your child component? That will be much easy. Please update your question with the code.

Comment: Using Redux will be much helpful and stress free. Traditional params passing method will be hectic sometimes when you have multiple routes.

Comment: @pKay gave an answer. Please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js)

Comment: @BrijeshBhakta i am learning redux , hope that will solve the problem . thanks .

Comment: @pKay, sure it will solve the problem. But I suggest to play around with just react and then move to redux.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass from parent to child you can pass using props and if you wan t to do reverse than you can pass one function from parent to child and than use this passed function to send something back to parent.

child will look something like this

```
class Reciepe extends Component{
    render(){
        const { title, img, instructions } = this.props;
        const ingredients=this.props.ingredients.map((ing,index)=>(<li key={index} >{ing}</li>));
        return (
            <div className='recipe-card'>
                <div className='recipe-card-img'> <img src={img} alt={title}/> </div>
                <div className='recipe-card-content'>
                    <h3 className='recipe-title'>Reciepe {title}</h3>
                    <ul> {ingredients} </ul>
                    <h4>Instructions:</h4>
                    <p>{instructions}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

parent will look something like this

```
class RecipeList extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{'display':'flex'}}>
                {this.props.recipes.map((item,index)=>(
                    <Recipe key={index}
                        title={item.title}
                        ingredients={item.ingredients}
                        instructions={item.instructions}
                        img={item.img}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you are passing some properties in Recipe component . this will work first time but when when i update one of the property (i.e title in your case ) by using setState then child compoent will get rendered with old props since setState is async it takes time to update. so how do we solve that. i have posted the code also . you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning the values to this which is not a good practice. Check where to declare variable in React [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417217/where-to-declare-variable-in-react-js/47417651#47417651).

If you are not using the props to do any complex operations. This should work.

```js
EmpList Componet

import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class Emp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.next)
            return <div>name not found</div>;
        else
          return (
              <div>
                  <br/>
                  <p>The list is here</p>
                  <ul>
                      {this.props.emp && this.props.emp.map(e => <li>{e.name}</li>)}
                  </ul>
              </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your next and emplist class properties are directly derivable from your props and hence you don't actually need them. You could do it in the following way

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

export default class Emp extends Component{

    render(){
        const { emp } = this.props;
        if(!emp || emp.length === 1)
            return <div>name not found</div>
        else {
           return (
              <div> 
                 <br/> <p>The list is here</p>
                 <ul>
                   {emp.map(e=>{return <li>{e.name}</li>});}
                 </ul>
              </div>
           )
       }
    }
}
```

---

However in cases when you do what to make really complex decisions based on props, a combination of `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidMount/componentWillMount` is the right place to do it.