# How to access the typed value of a child in an element

Tags: reactjs

I want to access the value of a textfield that's being created by React. The code is below:

```
class Paragraph extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let style = {
      height: "150px",
      marginBottom: "10px"
    };

    return (
      <div className="paragraph" id={this.props.id}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-11">
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              name={"paragraph" + this.props.id}
              placeholder="Put Paragraph Here"
              style={style}
              required
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-1">
            <div
              className="btn btn-danger del-rotate"
              onClick={() => this.props.remove(this.props.id)}
            >
              &times;
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using an index.js, which contains an App and adds a Paragraph. I want to access the value typed in the textarea from my index.js, which uses Paragraph. How do I do this?

Comment: `onChange()` attribute

Comment: Did you read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html?

Comment: Are you asking how to access `value` of `textarea` inside of **child** from a **parent** component? https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html and this https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag

Comment: @goto1, yes I want to access the value inside the textarea from a parent class

Comment: Those two links I shared will help you.

Comment: use props for the communication, and then pass it along. also don't forget to add change handler to your text area

Answer (score 3):

## You control the values

In react when you have an input you must control the state of that input.

### simple example

Using the react function useState we can control this input. state will always be our value.

```
const myComp = () => {
  const [state, changeState] = useState('');
  return <input type="text" onChange={e => changeState(e.target.value)} value={state} />;
};
```

Comment: This still doesn't take care of OP's issue where he wants to access value of a `textarea` inside of `child` from the `parent`.

Comment: pass state and changeState to the child EZ

Answer (score 0):

use props for the communication, and then pass it along. also don't forget to add change handler to your text area

For component communication :

[React | pass data from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952882/react-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component)

[How to pass data from parent to child in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483868/how-to-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-in-react-js)

https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

A sample for your case:

```
class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      textareaValue: ''
    }
  }
  handleOnChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      textareaValue: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
              <textarea  
                   rows={10} 
                   cols={30} 
                   value= {this.state.textareaValue} 
                   onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event)}>
             </textarea>
           </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead you can mention what needs to be changed will make it a nice answer.

Comment: You're not using `props` for communication as you suggested though.

Comment: @goto1 Its just a sample. Have provided few links though regarding component interaction